# What is the thinnest spot on the ilium called?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, bone

Is there a specific name for the spot on the human iliac fossa where the bone is the thinnest? (Or, is there a name for the thickness measurement of that spot, e.g. *the left/right _________ is 2.1mm*?)

Green arrow:

[image]
(image source: my own pelvis)

This point, for example (color maps thickness):

[image]
(image source: me)

Comment: The region is called iliac fossa. And it's basically the deepest part of the fossa. May be!!! I have never heard of a particular name of that thinnest part in my osteology books.

Comment: @A.N.Ψ it would just be called the thinnest or deepest part of the fossa, there is no special name for parts of a fossa you just use basic descriptive terms.